# Boot from multiple USB drives

Tags: windows-7, usb, hard-drive, bootable-media

I want to setup a bootable USB drive for Windows7. As I read from tutorials everywhere, I need at least a 4GB drive to store the setup files. The problem is I don't have a single 4GB drive. I have two 2GB drives. Is there a way to make these two drives together become bootable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. Because once you used the first, it has to have enough of the OS loaded to provide driver to load the second. There are ways to slipstream Windows to have a smaller footprint, but in your case, I recommend getting a bigger USB drive/SD card - it's < $10 now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. OK, I guess I just have to buy a bigger card. Btw, you mentioned SD card. Can I actually boot from SD card as well? Is the process similar to how we do it for USB drive?

Comment: Depending on your motherboard, the answers are "yes" and "yes". You just select the SD card in a higher position on the boot sequence. Make sure your SD card is at least Class 6 or above. Class 4 is tolerable, though may be a bit slow for an OS to run from. Class 2 is a recipe for disaster.